# Where is the documentation for what `%(something)` expansions work in `ansible.cfg`?

Tags: ansible

The title mostly says it all.

The reason I think any work is the [documentation for the `control_path` setting](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_configuration.html#control-path):

> This is the location to save ControlPath sockets. This defaults to:
>
> `control_path=%(directory)s/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r`
>
> On some systems with very long hostnames or very long path names
> (caused by long user names or deeply nested home directories) this can
> exceed the character limit on file socket names (108 characters for
> most platforms). In that case, you may wish to shorten the string to
> something like the below:
>
> `control_path = %(directory)s/%%h-%%r`
>
> Ansible 1.4 and later will instruct users to run with “-vvvv” in
> situations where it hits this problem and if so it is easy to tell
> there is too long of a Control Path filename. This may be frequently
> encountered on EC2. This setting is ignored if -o ControlPath is set
> in ssh_args.

The documentation never specifies what value `directory` has, or what other things could be put in here. Is there anywhere that does?

Comment: Read the very next section of the documentation, or the previous section of the ansible.cfg file.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - Oh, interesting. And that's the _only_ variable substitution that's supported in `ansible.cfg`?

Comment: That's the only one I've ever seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Newer documentation of ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL_PATH](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-ssh-control-path) (Google likes old versions for some reason) mentions `%(directory)` and omits quite a few words about path length limit.

> This is the location to save ssh’s ControlPath sockets, it uses ssh’s
> variable substitution. Since 2.3, if null, ansible will generate a
> unique hash. Use `%(directory)`s to indicate where to use the control
> dir path setting. Before 2.3 it defaulted to
> `control_path=%(directory)s/ansible-ssh-%%h-%%p-%%r`. Be aware that this
> setting is ignored if `-o ControlPath` is set in ssh args.

ANSIBLE_SSH_CONTROL_PATH_DIR is next in the config definitions.

> This sets the directory to use for ssh control path if the control
> path setting is null. Also, provides the `%(directory)`s variable for
> the control path setting.

Substitution is implemented with custom code in the ssh connection plugin, doing Python (not Jinja) string templating. ssh connection code is among the oldest in Ansible, this is a  legacy pattern that never become popular.

In general, an Ansible plugin or module will list anything special about the value you can provide.

Comment: Thanks, and thanks even more for the more detailed explanation. I did know about `%()s` substitution in `.ini` files in Python. I've actually written `.ini` file parsers that use it. :-) But, other people might not, and a more complete answer is better than a less complete answer.